# feature based slam mapping

Tags: slam, navigation, laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

Is there any ROS package for feature/landmark based SLAM that can work with laser and odometry information?

Can you give me any advice?

I appreciate your reply.

Best regards

Hossain

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189311/feature-based-slam-mapping/) by [cognitiveRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6861/cognitiverobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2014-08-07

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I´m not aware of a existing ROS implementation that is ready to use. This is likely also related to the fact that LIDAR/grid map based approaches work very well in most environments used with robots. I´d recommend taking a look at [openslam.org](https://openslam.org/). You´ll find quite a few approaches there and it sounds like a combination of [FLIRTLib](https://openslam.org/flirtlib.html) with some feature based estimation approach (like your own EKF, [CEKFSLAM](https://openslam.org/cekfslam.html), [this EKF](https://openslam.org/bailey-slam.html) or one of the pose graph implementations available there) would be an option for implementation.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-08-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cognitiveRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6861/cognitiverobot/) on 2014-08-07**:
Thanks stefan. I appreciate your reply. I know about openslam. Those EKF slam are implemented in matlab. FLIRTLib uses image. but i have to use for LASER and I was looking for ROS node or C++ code.

**Comment by [cognitiveRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6861/cognitiverobot/) on 2014-08-07**:
Hi Stefan, Did you use EKF-SLAM (provided by Tim Bailey)? I can use his matlab simulator. I works where features are points. Do you know whether it works with line features instead of the point features?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

openslam.org is a great resource as mentioned before.

Specifically in ROS, the one that work out of the box is

GMAPPING

http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping

http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData

OMNIMAPPER has been proposed recently.

https://github.com/CognitiveRobotics/omnimapper/wiki/FAQ
https://github.com/CognitiveRobotics/omnimapper/wiki/Dependencies-&-Installation
https://github.com/CognitiveRobotics/omnimapper/tree/master/ros/omnimapper_ros

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2014-08-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cognitiveRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6861/cognitiverobot/) on 2014-08-07**:
Thanks sai, I'm using gmapping for a while. Now I need to use line feature based SLAM to compare with my result. I'm going through OMNIMAPPER to see whether it does.

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2014-08-07**:
You can look at these publications

A. J. B. Trevor, J. G. Rogers III, H. I. Christensen, “OmniMapper: A modular multimodal mapping
framework”, ICRA, 2014 [pdf].

A. J. B. Trevor, J. G. Rogers III, H. I. Christensen, “Planar Surface SLAM with 3D and 2D Sensors”, ICRA, 2012. [pdf]

**Comment by [cognitiveRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6861/cognitiverobot/) on 2014-08-07**:
Thanks sai for those papers. Looking like that's what i'm looking for. Did you use the OmniMapper??

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2014-08-08**:
No, I didn't use it. Once you have successfully used it, you can share your experiences.

**Comment by [cognitiveRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6861/cognitiverobot/) on 2014-08-08**:
Ok. If i manage to use it then i will share my experience.

**Comment by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on 2014-10-29**:
It seems that Omnimapper cannot compile... Has anyone successfully compiled it?